# How to hide all boot text in Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

When the raspberry pi booting, how to remove all the boot text we are seeing in the Raspberry pi. Once the raspberry pi booted, it shows nothing but after few time going to the desktop. No terminal booting commands are showing. Can someone has a solutions for this ?

Comment: you mean after booting, it go direct to the desktop GUI instead of terminal ?

Comment: No exactly. When the raspberry pi booting, it shows some gibberish terminal commands scrolling. I know i can get the default Desktop using raspi-config and select the Desktop GUI instead of terminal. What i need is to hide all those terminal process that i see once it booting.

Comment: so you want to keep the terminal but don't want the text scrolling

Comment: Yes. I need to HIDE all that booting text scrolling in the boot up process.

Comment: I've made the answer. This way work well with me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me too.

***sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt***

change `console=tty1` to `console=tty3`

add these at the end of the line: `loglevel=3 quiet logo.nologo`

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add `loglevel=1` to ***cmdline.txt*** in the */boot* partition

More detail [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=17269&p=174897)